# How are extension developers allowing users to customize features like linting?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm working on a VSCode extension that has a linting feature.  The linter can be customized quite a bit.  How are folks allowing users to customize a feature like this?  Completely in user preference settings?  Specially named file?  User preference setting that specifies path to a settings file?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you can have a `.vscode\settings.json` file that allows global user preferences to be overridden on a per-workspace basis.